# Double has_many association return only one of the second association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, model-associations

```
Class Doctor
  has_many :patients
end

Class Patient
  belongs_to :doctor
  has_many :historics
end

Class Historic
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

I have a structure like this one. When I am a Doctor, I want to get a list of all my patients but only display the last historic of each one.

So far I was not able to find how to do it. Should I create something like this ?

```
Class Doctor
  has_many :patients_with_one_historic, class_name: 'Historic', :through => :patient, :limit => 1
end
```

But in this case this will return me Historic models of patient not Patient models with one historic ?!

*I'm using Rails 5.1.5*

Comment: Define 2 association as I provided in my answer for `patient- historic` relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers.
What I ended up doing is, since I use [fast_jsonapi](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi), to create a new "light" Patient `Serializer`.

Instead of having :

```
class PatientSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  set_type :patient
  attributes  :id,
              ......
              :historics
end
```

I have now :

```
class PatientSerializerLight
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  set_type :patient
  attributes  :id,
              ......
              :last_historic
end
```

In my Patient model I have created a method as @F.E.A suggested :

```
def last_historic
  self.historics.last
end
```

Now I can do :

```
@patients = @doctor.patients
PatientSerializerLight.new(@patients).serializable_hash
```

Maybe this is not very "rails way" but this work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in a case like this one, writing your own getter won't be the end of the world.

You may try something like this:

```
class Patient
  belongs_to :doctor
  has_many :historics

  # Get the latest historic
  def latest_historic
    self.historics.last
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks ! How would you call this method from the doctor ? `@doctor.patients.latest_historic` ?

Comment: @Stéphane you can call it from any individual patient, as patient.latest_historic. You can call doctor.patients and map it like doctor.patients.map{|p| p.latest_historic} to get your latest historics as collection.

Answer (score 0):

You need a different setup.

First off, the direct relation is: A Doctor has many patients.

```
Class Doctor
  has_many :patients
end
Class Patient
  belongs_to :doctor
end
```

now that you have established this connection you need to add the additional association with historics:

```
Class Patient
  belongs_to :doctor
  has_many :historics
end

Class Historic
  belongs_to :doctor
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

and finally, adjust Doctor:

```
Class Doctor
  has_many :patients
  has_many :historics, through: :patients
end
```

inside your console:

```
d = Doctor.last

d.patients.last.historics.last
```